# How to prefill UnitPrice on Order Products

Tags: order, pricebookentry, orderitem

I want my Order Product price to prefill based on the price defined on the Pricebook Entry. I swear I've seen this work in the past, but I can't figure out why this time I keep getting an empty field on the second step of the 'Add products' modals.

Is this a standard feature? Can I control this in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, this *is* standard functionality, but the UnitPrice only gets filled when the ListPrice field is included in the Search Layout used by the Pricebook Entry object.